# MariaDB, export data using degraded version of table structure

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I have 2 MariaDB database schemas of the same application. One is the schema of application V1 and the other is of V2.

V2 schema has a lot of test data. I am setting up a test environment of application V1, which need V1 database schema, but would like to have all test data inside V2 schema.

Mostly, V2 schema is V1 with some more columns and tables.

Is there a way to export data from V2 schema by telling the tool (such as mysqldump) that I would like it to use V1 table structure, so that it ignores missing columns and tables.

Answer (score 0):

Mysqldump doesn't have an option like you describe.

There's an option `--insert-ignore` which causes the output of mysqldump to contain a series of `INSERT IGNORE` statements. But this won't do what you want.

The result of `INSERT IGNORE` is that if an `INSERT` fails, it skips those rows. But you want it to insert the rows, without the extra columns in your V2 dump.

I'm afraid your options are one of:

- ALTER TABLE on your V2 database to match the tables and columns of your V1 schema, then dump the data.
- Restore the V2 database, including the extra tables and columns, then ALTER TABLE to remove those that are extra.
- Write your own tool that works sort of like mysqldump, except you get to specify which columns to dump per table.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

`CREATE VIEWs` for each V1 table structure.

`mysqldump` ... specifying just the Views be dumped.